# cannot resolve keyword 'activate' into field

Tags: python, django

This is my error
FieldError at /Slife/

Cannot resolve keyword 'activate' into field. Choices are: active, comment, created, details, featured, id, image, modified, name, option, slug, views

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/Slife/
Django Version:     2.2.1
Exception Type:     FieldError
Exception Value:

Cannot resolve keyword 'activate' into field. Choices are: active, comment, created, details, featured, id, image, modified, name, option, slug, views

Exception Location:     C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in names_to_path, line 1420
Python Executable:  C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:

['C:\Users\essum\Envs\LIFE',
 'C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\Scripts\python37.zip',
 'C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib',
 'C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\Scripts',
 'c:\users\essum\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Lib',
 'c:\users\essum\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1',
 'C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 10 Jun 2019 09:56:18 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner

                response = get_response(request)

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\LIFE\Slife\views.py in home

        categories = Category.objects.filter(activate=True,views__gte=3000).order_by('-views')

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py in manager_method

                    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in filter

            return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in _filter_or_exclude

                clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in add_q

            clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in _add_q

                        split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in build_filter

            lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in solve_lookup_type

            _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())

     …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\essum\Envs\Py1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in names_to_path

                                         "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

     …
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: help,,,new to python django

Answer (score 2):

This line tells you what is wrong

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'activate' into field. Choices are: active, comment, created, details, featured, id, image, modified, name, option, slug, views
```

You need to change the line with the error to

```
        categories = Category.objects.filter(active=True,views__gte=3000).order_by('-views')
```

Your model has a field called 'active', but you are trying to filter on the field 'activate' which doesn't exist.